# Nvidia GeForce 9400 GT failing on POST on one PC but working just fine on the other

Tags: windows-8.1, drivers, graphics-card, gpu, nvidia-geforce

My graphic card is Nvidia GeForce 9400 GT, I earlier used it on a AMD Sempron 145 powered PC with 2 gb ram running win 7, and it worked perfectly. Lately I bought a core 2 duo (e6750) with 4 gb ram and gugabyte MB running win 8.1.

the new windows 8.1 PC is unable to configure and use the GPU (shows the BSOD video_tds_failure error) when appropriate drivers installed, also the windows is not able to adopt the native screen res of my monitor (1366 x 768). But, the same GPU still functions well on my old win 7 system with the same graphic drivers!

if I run my new system without GPU and update the on-board drivers, the OS runs smoothely, so clearly, my GPU is not supported on this system, while it should be, any ideas why is this happening, and solutions are most welcome for this problem.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Ask the company that made your computers whether they use a BIOS or a UEFI.  Graphics board that old often will allow booting only on computers that use a BIOS.  The type of CPU is not an issue for this problem.

Also, graphics boards that old are often not supported by the newest drivers.  Try this web site which recognizes that older board often need older versions of the drivers:

http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us